# How to change the date format in Nautilus list columns?

Tags: nautilus, settings, date

The date format of the date columns is really long "Tue 12 June 2012 17:12:34 PHT". I would prefer a shorter version, e.g. 12/06/2012 or 12/06/2012 17:12.
I tried to change it in Settings/Language Support or Time&Date, but did not find an option to influence the length of the date/time format.
Any hint?

Comment: We, Ubuntu 18.04, 18.10, and 19.04 users are still waiting for solution to this problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is a vacuum for changing date format of the date columns in Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 18.04 and following (18.10, 19.04, 19.10, 20.04).** (Neither dconf, gconf nor gsettings works, there is no date-format setting option.)
There are some **workarounds**, see [How to show full date and time in Nautilus/Files 3.6+ list view](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285493/how-to-show-full-date-and-time-in-nautilus-files-3-6-list-view).
**Bug reports** are opened on [Gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/949) and [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774492), please add your comments or help if you have the expertise as there has been **no progress for years**!

With other problems, e.g. **[Bug #1152226 “nautilus no longer remembers view per directory”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1152226)** and [View mode setting should persistent for each directory](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=683802), Nautilus is more and more **user-UNfriendly** and a **switch** to Nemo or other **alternative file browser** like Thunar is to consider.

**ONLY Ubuntu 17.04 & 17.10** in a terminal (not in 18.04):

- `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences date-format iso`
- `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences date-format locale`
- `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences date-format informal`
  [Credit goes to Pablo Bianchi, see his comment.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149890/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-nautilus-list-columns/149891?noredirect=1#comment1620347_149891)

**For Caja (Mate 17.04)**: [See other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/149899/30631)

**Only works up to Ubuntu 12.04, maybe 13.10** (not 14.04 and 16.04)**:**
Install **dconf-editor** (available in the normal repository), navigate to:
org>gnome>nautilus>preferences>date-format, then click on the field "value" beside the date-format field and a drop-down menu appears with the three choices:

- locale   = Tue 12 June 2012 17:12:34 PHT
- iso      = 2012-06-12 17:12:34
- informal = Today at 5:12:34 PM or Tuesday, June 12 2012 5:12:34 PM

I chose iso and am happy.

Comment: Does not work in 14.04.

Comment: Does not work in 16.04.

Comment: Terminal way: `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences date-format iso`.

Comment: @PabloBianchi does not work 19.10 
xxx@yyy:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences date-format iso
No such key “date-format”
xxx@yyy:~$ gsettings list-keys org.gnome.nautilus.preferences
search-filter-time-type
<snip - date-* not there>
show-image-thumbnails
confirm-trash
search-view
thumbnail-limit
mouse-back-button
click-policy
mouse-forward-button
show-create-link
show-directory-item-counts
mouse-use-extra-buttons
executable-text-activation
show-delete-permanently
fts-enabled
default-folder-viewer
use-experimental-views
install-mime-activation

Comment: @brewmanz Seems related to [this bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/949), I'm not sure if `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser date-format` is related.

Answer (score 4):

User does not need to install **dconf-editor** to accomplish a date format change in Nautilus. It can be done via Nautilus' Preferences.

```
Edit > Preferences > "Display" tab
look for the "Format" section under the "Date" heading
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why did I not spot that? dconf-editor might be still worth to install to edit other settings, e.g. date format of the date-indicator: askubuntu.com/questions/43999/how-to-change-the-date-format

Comment: Not available in 13.04, how can it be done now?

Comment: Not available in 14.04 either. Please update this answer.

Comment: Also does not work in 16.04.

Comment: Worked in 17.04 Zesty as Mate Caja.  Thanks.

Comment: Does not work in 18.04.

Comment: Does not work in 19.04 ....

Comment: Nothing new in **19.10** either! :(

Comment: Does not work in 20.04