# How to show full date and time in Nautilus/Files 3.6+ list view?

Tags: nautilus

The list view of Nautilus 3.6 shows the dates files were modified in a variety of ways: the hour and minute if modified on the current day, and the month and day if modified during the current year, and the year tacked on if modified during a previous year. I would like to see the entire date and time consistently on all the files (e.g.: `Sat 20 Apr 2012 01:28:34 PM EDT`).

I had this set up before, but I can't figure out how to do so with version 3.6. I did find this question, but the answers no longer apply to Nautilus 3.6: [How to change the date format in Nautilus list columns?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149890/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-nautilus-list-columns)

How can I do so in Nautilus 3.6+?

Comment: Looking at the settings on precise and raring they are identical so I am assuming it is a feature removed from nautilus there maybe a plugin or script that can re-add it though.

Comment: the date-format key in gsettings was removed by this commit: https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/libnautilus-private/org.gnome.nautilus.gschema.xml.in?id=73465be3671ae572ba744d36b055fda3cb210db7 which belongs to this bug report: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676898

Comment: A link to a "bug" asking that the functionality be restored: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699055

Comment: Happening to me on v3.14.2. A person named Carlos commented in https://goo.gl/AE7FRA that this is fixed in nautilus v3.16.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Can anyone confirm whether this was fixed or not? In the Nautilus that ships with Ubuntu 16?

Comment: @becko Ubuntu 16.04 ships with Nautilus 3.14. It is not fixed in that version. I have not tested 3.16.

Comment: Switch to Thunar.

Comment: What about now? Any fixes on this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can get back the full date by recompiling nautilus:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus
sudo apt-get install quilt
export QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches
apt-get source nautilus
cd nautilus*
quilt new 999_full_dates.patch
quilt edit libnautilus-private/nautilus-column-utilities.c
```

Change line 77 from

```
"attribute", "date_modified",
```

to

```
"attribute", "date_modified_full",
```

Rebuild and install modified package:

```
quilt refresh
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage
cd ..
killall nautilus
sudo dpkg -i nautilus_*.deb
nautilus &
```

As always, you have to perform these steps every time there is an update for nautilus in Ubuntu.

Now, a full analysis of the problem:

The actual patch which caused this change [is this one](https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?id=3fd9cba41e56f44ed955b28755ad03135026d021).

The function `nautilus_file_get_date_as_string` gains an extra gboolean parameter "compact" - when true the abbreviated date is returned.

This function is never called directly - it is accessed through the wrapper function `nautilus_file_get_string_attribute_q`. This function takes attribute parameters like "date_modified". To accommodate the new signature of `nautilus_file_get_date_as_string` a new attribute is added "`date_modified_full`". After this change, any code in nautilus which uses the file date string will get the abbreviated date.

Finally, the file properties dialog is updated to use "date_modified_full" attribute.

So in order to have nautilus display the full date in list view, it is only necessary to change one line of code: in libnautilus-private/nautilus-column-utilities.c, line 77 from "date_modified" to "date_modified_full".

[A slightly more useful patch](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5605682/) could add a new column type which would show the full date, making this an optional feature, and only add 10 lines of code.

Comment: This is why I love open source - when the developers go crazy, I can fix it myself.

Comment: This is why I love open source - people like you can fix things when developers go crazy. Thank you!

Comment: One minor downside: now if you type home into the dash the home folder it doesn't show up. Typing the username still works though. Not sure why this is, but it's a pretty minor issue.

Comment: It doesn't show up for me either. I have an unpatched nautilus installed. I don't see how this change could cause a difference in the dash. Can you test with unpatched nautilus please?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it doesn't show up for me now. I now wonder if it ever did in 13.04? Not a big deal, but odd.

Comment: Is this currently still the only way to handle this issue?

Comment: @AlistairBuxton Have you tried submitting the second patch to the Gnome developers? It would be great if they could at least give us a choice instead of keeping the full date unavailable…

Comment: I no longer use Nautilus and I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Has this been fixed in more recent versions (so that I don't have to recompile)?

Comment: What about now? Any updates? Ubuntu is dropping Unity in favor of GNOME, sure some things have changed.

Answer (score 19):

This [blog post](https://www.fabianfier.de/blog1.php/nautilus-3-10-on-ubuntu) shows a much easier solution. It is based on creating an extension which can be selected as an alternative "modified column". Tested under 16.04.

1. `gedit ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/longdate.py`
2. Use this code (always copy code you trust):

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python

   import os
   import urllib
   import datetime
   from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject

   class ColumnExtension(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.ColumnProvider, Nautilus.InfoProvider):
       def __init__(self):
           pass

       def get_columns(self):
           return (Nautilus.Column(
               name="NautilusPython::Longdate", 
               attribute="longdate", 
               label="Longdate", 
               description="Get long date"),)

       def update_file_info(self, file):
           if file.get_uri_scheme() != 'file':
               return

           filename = urllib.unquote(file.get_uri()[7:])
           statbuf = os.stat(filename)
           formatteddate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(statbuf.st_mtime).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
           file.add_string_attribute('longdate', str(formatteddate))
   ```
3. `chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/longdate.py`
4. `sudo apt install python-nautilus`
5. `nautilus -q` and `nautilus .` to restart Nautilus and see if it properly loads the extension.
6. Select the new "Longdate" column in the list column preferences.

The result will look like this:

[image: example]

Comment: First install nautilus-python: `sudo apt-get install python-nautilus`

Comment: Thanks a lot - it seems to work in Disco - Ubuntu 19.04 ! But you can not sort by Longdate. Unfortunately I can not fix that myself. Great job anyways. As @Alistair Buxton  said: This is why I love open source - when the developers go crazy, I can fix it myself. Well, with your help! THX.

Comment: This isn't working on Nautilus ("Files" 3.10.1) on Ubuntu 14.04.  When Nautilus is started from command line, it says `Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory` Please ask sysadm to enable user sharing.  Then six times `** (nautilus:21161): CRITICAL **: nautilus_menu_provider_get_background_items: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_FILE_INFO (current_folder)' failed`.  The would-be new column doesn't show in the choices.

Comment: Thanks ! Works for me under Bionic (18.04.4 LTS), Nautilus 3.26.4 and nautilus-python 1.1-6.

Comment: [Here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/949#note_612911) is another solution you should only use if you read it or trust it.

Comment: Even though you can't sort by Longdate, you can still show the useless Modfied column and sort by that.

Comment: Ubuntu 22: the package was replaced by `python3-nautilus` and `unquote` was moved under `parse` - so you need to do `urllib.parse.unquote` instead of just `urllib.unquote`, (+ `import urllib.parse`) otherwise still works :-) didn't figure out the sorting yet... Also it doesn't seem to work in the Icon View Captions. For sorting I just display "Modified --- Time" too and sort by that - which effectively sorts this column too :-)

Answer (score 6):

For those using `trusty` & not wishing to compile I've set up a test ppa for a patched nautilus. (using Alistair Buxton's patch

The build currently also includes 2 bug fix patches, 1 from trusty-proposed, 1 from utopic.

Additionally there are 3 minor patches that have been tested by me over quite some time & pose no issues.

1. open with on folders
2. real file owner name displayed instead of "Me"
3. File Manager as name of launcher

The 'date-time' patch I've tested a bit, seen no issues. For those inclined to try - if any issue found contact me thru launchpad email.

The "Modified (full)" column can be added thru nautilus in `listview` > View > Visible Columns..  or thru nautilus > Edit > Preferences > List Columns

https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/nauty-mods

Read ppa page for info & how to easily revert if need be.

Comment: I can't seem to get this nautilus version installed. `sudo apt-get install nautilus` just concludes that `latest is already installed`. Trying `sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus` reinstalls, but the very same that there already is. Do you by any chance have something for e.g. `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` that makes this thing actually get installed, or how else to do it?  (on Trusty)

Comment: @ Hannu, try again, needed to be updated

Comment: `dpkg --list | grep nautilus` showed the `...+date` version. Retried, several times. Only after having rebooted with this version installed, then delved into the Terminal and there after using `nautilus --no-desktop` (unsure if it appeared there) and then `nautilus --force-desktop` I - at last - found the "Modified (full)" option in the list view. Now it seems to be present at all times. **question**: Can the content be modified? e.g. I'd hope as for use of "strftime()" ?

Comment: Hmm... might it be `LC_TIME=...` that specifies the format?

Comment: @ Hannu, no clue as to why you found the list view option so 'hard' to find, no such issues here. As far as modifying,  well download the debian.tar.xz file from ppa, you'll find the date-time.patch inside the patches folder, have at it.

Comment: An unprejudiced request for next time you update the ppa, please consider adding yet another format for the Modifed column; same as `date +'%Y-%m-%d, %T'`

Answer (score 4):

Nemo is a fork of Nautilus that includes Creation date and a button for Ctrl+L.

```
sudo apt install nemo
```

To [replace Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/1173861/42522) for Documents links etc.:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

That updates your mime settings:

```
$ cat ~/.config/mimeapps.list |grep inode
inode/directory=nemo.desktop
inode/directory=exo-file-manager.desktop;
$ cat /etc/gnome/defaults.list |grep inode
inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

Comment: how do i make it the default file manager?

Comment: @Michael I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have nemo on one of my devices, great usability, but terrible RAM issues - always check from time to time and restart it (and nemo-desktop too if you have it), I mean like GBs... :-)