# How to make Ubuntu show date AND time on Files screen?

Tags: time, date

Ubuntu 12.04 used to show date and time of files in directory in Files.  With 13.04, only date is shown (for files created before the current date).

How can I make date and time to show in Files on 13.04?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Right click on the file and select **Properties**. You will see when it was accessed and modified last time.

Comment: I look forward to the answer.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285493/how-to-show-full-date-and-time-in-nautilus-files-3-6-list-view - This thread explains that it's been removed and how you could get it back (involves recompiling).

Comment: I have just found this, don't know if it'll help.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/285493/how-to-show-full-date-and-time-in-nautilus-files-3-6-list-view?rq=1

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Hopefully they will put it back on the next update.