# Make Nautilus display ISO format for date-time (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: nautilus, 14.04, locale

I have locale set for en_DK

Nautilus still displays non-standardized date-time format. Is there a way to make it behave and display ISO standard?

Comment: Seems like Nautilus displays dates regardless of LC_TIME.

Comment: nautilus is completly useless when it can't even display date-time so you can know how files were modified.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 has the same problem

Comment: Relevant to 15.10 as well. Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/285493/13330

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be related to the removal of date format options - details can be found in this question:

[How to show full date and time in Nautilus/Files 3.6+ list view?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285493/how-to-show-full-date-and-time-in-nautilus-files-3-6-list-view)

I’m using en_AU and expect dates formatted *1 Jun* but see *Jun 1* instead.  Nautilus appears to ignore the locale.  I’d prefer the choice of a full date, but it should at least conform to the locale.

See also:

- [Full date and time cannot be viewed in "modified" list view column](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699055)
  (request for this change to be reverted)
- [Use a better date format by default instead of making the user guess](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676898)
  (original bug report that lead to the change)