# (Another) How to show full date and time in Nautilus/Files 3.10+ list view?

Tags: nautilus, timestamp

This question is essentially a follow up or continuation of:

[How to show full date and time in Nautilus/Files 3.6+ list view?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285493/how-to-show-full-date-and-time-in-nautilus-files-3-6-list-view/496073#496073)

...but b/c this isn't ANSWERING that question, I'm disallowed from asking this there.  So I've no other recourse except to ask a new question (or two).

The issue is a complaint that Nautilus/Files has been dumbed-down and does NOT show hour and minute (let alone seconds) information.  In the other "Ask", a method for patching the source code and recompiling is given and then also a method for just obtaining and installing a ppa is given.

I tried both the re-compile method and the ppa method shown in the original "Ask".  Neither one of those work for me.  I still just see the stripped/simplified/nearly-useless date stamp.

So my question is, can anyone elaborate on and help me get to getting the full date and timestamp?

I'm not sure if it's significant or not, but when running the "nautilus &" command shown in ...496073#496073, my terminal spits out:

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
tdb(__NULL__): tdb_open_ex: called with name == NULL
```

The recompile method (cut-and-pasted from the OrgAsk) is as follows:

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

You can get back the full date by recompiling nautilus:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus
sudo apt-get install quilt
export QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches
apt-get source nautilus
cd nautilus*
quilt new 999_full_dates.patch
quilt edit libnautilus-private/nautilus-column-utilities.c
```

Change line 77 from

```
"attribute", "date_modified",
```

to

```
"attribute", "date_modified_full",
```

Rebuild and install modified package:

```
quilt refresh
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage
cd ..
killall nautilus
sudo dpkg -i nautilus_*.deb
nautilus &
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

And the ppa method (also cut-and-pasted) is to visit:

https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/nauty-mods

Thanks. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You did the right thing, when you have the same problem but existing answers don't solve the problem ask a new question with a link back to the original. Then, once you get an answer we can merge them together if needed. One thing: Could you please re-explain the original question here? ([edit] your question to do that). That way people don't have to follow another link to actually figure out what your entire problem is. Thanks!

Comment: Nautilus/files has removed many useful features. I believe that the best way to get all the features of a nice file manager is to switch to Dolphin which I did and now I am very much content with it.

Comment: It is 5 years now and still we have the same problem.