# How can I see modification times in nautilus (instead of only dates)?

Tags: nautilus

I would like to increase the precision of column "modification" shown in Nautilus to include a time. This is under Unity.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285493/how-to-show-full-date-and-time-in-nautilus-files-3-6-list-view) related question (concerning an older nautilus version), but I consider the answer (recompiling nautilus) overkill for my purposes.

Comment: I've not found anything that can show date+exact time in the columns of list view. It is however possible to see exact date+time if you right click on the file. I've also sketched out a script that integrates into nautilus and can show a popup with filename and time via right click menu, but  it seems there's not a lot that can be done for list view

Comment: You might want to consider submitting a feature request to Nautilus developers on Launchpad

Answer (score 1):

There is a `dconf` setting which I think should control this behaviour, but it seems not to have any effect on Nautilus on my 16.04 Ubuntu (Unity desktop), it only affects file-choser windows like the "Open..." or "Save as..." dialogues of most applications.

You can get the current value of this setting using the command

```
gsettings get org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser date-format
```

The default is `regular`, the other option is `with-time`. You change the value with one of the two commands below.

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser date-format with-time
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser date-format regular
```

I am not sure whether it's a bug that this setting does not affect Nautilus or whether that is by design though. However, unfortunately I could not find anything closer to what you want.

Comment: +1, because it helps a bit, by giving the info in the "open.." dialogue...