# How can I change the modified field in the list view of a folder to be more precise?

Tags: gui, window, time, date

I'm a filmmaker and I'm trying to use Ubuntu to do some basic video editing.  If I try and use the GUI, I can only see the month and day of the time my video clips were edited.  I'd like to be able to see the hours and minutes.

Comment: Hours and minutes that it was last modified, or hours and minutes duration of the videos?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show full date and time in Nautilus/Files 3.6+ list view?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285493/how-to-show-full-date-and-time-in-nautilus-files-3-6-list-view)

Comment: You could also use Nemo as a replacement for Nautilus. http://askubuntu.com/search?q=nemo+default

Comment: No working solutions there ^ ^ to the current version. Saying "use something else" is not really an answer to the question.