# Display of dates/times in ISO 8601 format in Files (Nautilus)

Tags: nautilus, files, date

Is there a way to get the file manager Files (Nautilus?) and other applications under Ubuntu to display the date and time in standard ISO 8601 format, instead of the "comfortable" style, like "Yesterday 09:39".

I haven't been able to find an option anywhere to display date/time in ISO 8601 format in Files.  For example, right-clicking on the "Modified (date)" field in Files produces nothing useful in this regard, and trying Ubuntu Settings -> Date&Time gives me no choice at all for the date format.

Added -- And there is now nothing in Nautilus Permissions that allows a change of date format.

Shouldn't ISO 8601 be the standard for all applications under Ubuntu, and those users who don't want it should have to set their own option, somewhere?

Using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Sorry, no, the suggested solutions do not work in v20.04 (and apparently not since at least v18).  Is there another way, one that will work in v20?

Comment: [There](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018026/349837) is a link to [the open issue about this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/949), where you can find [this solution](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/949#note_612911). Another working solution is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018026/349837). Only copy source code you trust.

Comment: Thank you, All.  Not being brave enough to recompile Nautilus and having to do it again after each update, I decided eventually on the suggestions by @karel, choosing to install **Nemo** (a fork of Nautilus).  Changed the date format there easily using the preferences menu.  I will test Nemo for a while (it looks good so far), and perhaps try to recompile Nautilus later.  It remains a puzzle to me that the ISO 8601 option was removed from Nautilus.  Again, many thanks to everyone for their suggestions.  I really appreciate your help.