# How to change the date format in Nautilus/Files list columns?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, settings

I'd like to set Nautilus' date format to ISO-8601, but both of the old ways that answered the question [for 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149890/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-nautilus-list-columns) are no longer available. How can the date format be changed now?

Comment: Not gonna happen: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676898#c13. Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/460098/158442 If you **really** want it in Nautilus, head to https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699055

Comment: You might want to try Nemo, instead: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/nemo/

Comment: It seems like GNOME's Bugzilla isn't set up for any kind of voting. I hate to write a "me too" comment on there. How should I show my support for fixing this bug?

Comment: You could mark yourself as affected in the Launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1314821 and also leave a comment mentioning the Gnome bug. If it gets enough attention they may patch it for Ubuntu.